# Rails: ActionController::UrlGenerationError, No route matches, missing required keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The following error is displayed when I try to create new data.

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError (No route matches {:room_id=>nil, :action=>"index", :controller=>"events"} missing required keys: [:room_id]):
```

**models**

```
models/rooms.rb

      has_many :events, inverse_of: :room, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :amounts, inverse_of: :room, dependent: :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :events, allow_destroy: true

models/events.rb

      has_one :amount, inverse_of: :schedule, dependent: :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :amount, allow_destroy: true
```

**routes.rb**

```
...
  resources :events,              only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  resources :rooms do
    resources :events
  end

...
```

When I click `link_to` for `new_room_event_path(1)`, the above error is displayed.
It generates `root/rooms/1/events/new`.

**view**

```
    <% if logged_in? %>
      <% if current_user?(@user) %>
        <% if schedule.rooms.blank? %>
          <%= link_to "Add event", new_room_event_path(1), class: "btn btn-sn btn-primary" %>
          <br>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

The reason why I designate `new_room_event_path(1)` is that this is first time to create data.

**events_controller.rb**

```
  before_action :load_room

  def new

    @event = Event.new
    @event.room = @room
    @event.build_amount
    @event.amount.schedule = @room.schedule
    @event.amount.room = @room

  end

  private

    def load_room
      if Room.exists?(id: params[:room_id])
        @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
      else
        @room = Room.new
      end
    end
```

It could be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Comment: Does it have atleast one room created? Because you seem to be passing hard code value, so I am asking this...

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend removing the `resources :events, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]` from the routes file since you are using events as a nested resource under rooms.

Second, if you are creating a room that doesn't exist, it would probably be better to send them to the actual new_room_path where a room can be created, and you can make it a nested form if you want them to be able to add event(s) at the same time as creating the new room. If the room does already exist, then you can use the nested route as it was designed with `new_room_event_path(room)`

Looks like you were missing an association to room from your event model, don't forget

```
# models/event.rb

belongs_to :room
```

And then from your EventsController you can do this and not worry about a nil room

```
# controllers/events_controller.rb

before_action :set_room
before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

private

def set_room
  @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
end

def set_event
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources for more details on nested resources

Answer (score 0):

In your events controller, in the `new` action, change it to `@room = @event.room`. Your error is saying that it can't find a room_id. The way you have written it in your controller you are asking your new method to set @event.room to @room, but it's the first time the method has seen @room and has no idea what it is. By saying @room = @event.room, the new action understands as you have already, in the lines above, defined what @event is and so assigns the room_id to that @event.